# Problem making UITableViewCell text white when selected

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

When my user clicks on a cell I want the text to turn white:

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {

    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
    lblName.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor]; 
    lblTime.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
}
```

This works fine, but when the user selects another cell, the previous cell's text color remains white. How can I revert it back to black?

Comment: I suppose the code is just to showcase what you want to achieve? If not why don't you use the "selected" variable to decide which color you want to assign to your labels?

Comment: DOH. Thanks for pointing out the obvious. I should've seen that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSIndexPath *oldIndexPath;

    UITableViewCell *cell1 = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    UITableViewCell *cell2 = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:oldIndexPath];
    cell1.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    cell2.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    oldIndexPath = indexPath;
}
```